# Use one collider for Rigidbody2D.Cast, and another for a hurtbox

Tags: unity, 2d, collision-detection, rigidbody

I'd like to do the following:

- Characters (player, enemies) have a collider for collision with the world (= other characters/obstacles/etc)
- Characters have another collider acting as a hurtbox (most likely larger than the collision)

Now what I tried is a layout is like roughly this:

```markdown
Character root GameObject [layer is "default"]
  - Rigidbody2D (kinematic, full kinematic collision)
  - BoxCollider2D (rather small, just the feet of the sprite)
  - `MovementController` script with collision detection using `rigidbody.Cast` and MovementFilter set to layer "default"
  * `Hurtbox` child object [layer is "hurtbox"]
    - BoxCollider2D (covers most of the sprite (or more to make some enemies easy to hit))
```

LayerMatrix: Two user defined layers: Hitbox, Hurtbox. There's no interaction with the predefined layers and the only interactions among these is

```markdown
Hitbox - Hurtbox [used for damage, etc: when a hitbox collides with a hurtbox, things happen]
```

Now the problem seems to be that all the Colliders in the child objects attach themselves to the ribidbody in the parent even though they're on different layers. And so the `rigidbody.Cast` uses the combined shape of both the "collision" box collider AND the "hurtbox" box collider.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you considered using `footCollider.Cast()` instead of `rigidbody.Cast()`?

Comment: Lovely! This should solve it. I did not know that the colliders themselves also have the `Cast` method. (But out of curiosity: Is it possible to solve it at the level of the Rigidbody? The use case would be: The intended collision shape is a composite of several colliders, the intended hitbox is a composite of other colliders. Of course I could then do a `foreach` and cast all the hitbox colliders but it'd be great for my understanding if there's a top-level solution).

Comment: I'm not aware of a rigidbody-level solution offhand. I'd recommend posting an answer showing a solution with `Collider2D.Cast` for now, and see if any other suggestions arise.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution as proposed by @DMGregory.

The key is to use the collider itself for the `.Cast` instead of the rigidbody

Old code - irrelevant parts omitted

```
private Rigidbody2D rb;

void Start()
{
  rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

private bool HasCollision(Vector2 direction)
{
  int count = rb.Cast(
    direction,
    movementFilter,
    collisions,
    collisionOffset
  );

  return count > 0;
}
```

New code - irrelevant parts omitted:

```
private Rigidbody2D rb;
private Collider2D collider;

void Start()
{
  rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
  collider = GetComponent<Collider2D>();
}

private bool HasCollision(Vector2 direction)
{
  // Here's the key change!
  int count = collider.Cast(
    direction,
    movementFilter,
    collisions,
    collisionOffset
  );

  return count > 0;
}
```

This works, but it'd be still great to hear about a solution solely based on nested objects and layers. The use case would be to allow for composite colission shapes without resorting to something like a `foreach` where every step in the iteration does a  `.Cast`.